# WebVR with Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, webvr

I have been following webvr [sample](https://webvr.info/samples/XX-vr-controllers.html) and successfully got it working inside my application. I also have a Forge-viewer running in my app.

Now my goal is to merge these two into one view, so that I can see my controllers inside forge viewer. is there any way of loading my webvr canvas inside forge viewer? or is there any better way to do it?

I have tried working with webvr forge extension, but i keep running into errors.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateCamera' of undefined
>       at Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.WebVR.VRTool.update (WebVR.js:519).

same error appears in herouku sample.

Comment: What version of the viewer are you currently using, I don't believe the webVR extension the viewer comes with, has out of the box support for external webVR applications. Maybe explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to do and what part of your code is the one causing this error

Comment: figured out that webvr extension for forge doesn't support controller. So we ended up adding our own functionality of adding controller support in webVR extension. viewer version is the default it loads I guess 2.12.. I haven't specified a specific version.

Comment: Ok, I will suggest try to use a newer version to have a better performance with the use of the webVR extension.
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/